# volatility Table and BS formula

Tags: volatility, black-scholes, implied-volatility, fx

assume I have implied FX volatility Delta-Term table from broker. I have time noticed as 2M, 3M. what do I have to put into BS formula, is it 2/12 or "count the business days"/"daycount basis"?
I am confused with the notion of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its 2months and 3 months, respectively, adjusted for banking holidays that may fall on the sought after day and the local convention of whether you then move to the next or previous business day.

Comment: so, my second calculation, right (count the business days/daycount basis)?

Comment: generally yes. Its much more precise

Comment: ok, but for 1y (and only) thankfully it will be still just 1? and regardless convension

Comment: No for any tenor you should optimally derive the precise expiration date using local market conventions.

Comment: so what means 1y? if this is "business days in 1y"/"daycount" so i.e. 252/365 ?

Comment: You did not provide sufficient information to answer that question. You need to check out the specific day count convention that applies to your product and market. By the way if this is just a modeling exercise then you can call the shots yourself as there is no contract in which two parties agree on the exact expiration date. There is no single right or wrong answer here if no contract is involved. Some fully count weekends others don't and again others partially include them. I recommend reading Taleb's "Dynamic Hedging" for more detail.

Comment: thank you, I like Taleb's books. I have to know exactly how is time measured because I calculate strikes from delta-term vol surface